# MySQL: Avoid filesort when using ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, filesort

```
    CREATE TABLE table1 (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`kid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`table_group` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL)
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I Got index on following Column;

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
KEY `index1` (`kid`,`table_group`);
```

The table has 5million rows matching to the where clause; When i do a explain on the below query its doing filesort and the runtime with limit its take 10seconds which is very high.

```
mysql> explain select * from db1.table1 FORCE INDEX(index1) where kid=187 and table_group in ('NOT_PRESENT', 'NOTHING', 'PERROR') order by id limit 200\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: tabl1
         type: range
possible_keys: index1
          key: index1
      key_len: 306
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1052764
        Extra: Using index condition; Using filesort
```

I want to avoid this filesort; Please help

Comment: you can't. you're using an `order by` clause. the db has NO idea in advance just how many records are going to be found, so it has to cache the results in a temp file so it can do the sort/limit.

Comment: You are having 1052764 rows matching the condition and would not fit to the memory. If the filtering is better, you can get it out

Comment: you can get ordered results without filesort. to say otherwise is just untrue.

Comment: you can try remove your `FORCE INDEX(index1)` and check explain to see if mysql can do `ORDER BY` using primary key. or try to add `id` into your `index1` key

Comment: Why would you force an index like that? Trying to outperform planner job? We don't know the distribution of values in your index. You shouldn't force indexing in production.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE table1` and `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`.  There are a few subtle issues I need to see before commenting further.  Also, what version of MySQL are you running?  (This is an area where there have been changes recently.)